# Best way of creating a Comparator that reverses order

Tags: java, sorting, reverse, comparator

This may seem like a dumb question, but I'd like to inquire about the best way to sort in reverse order a sortable structure (any kind, could be `List`) of a class `MyClass` that doesn't implement `Comparable`

First off, since `MyClass` doesn't implement `Comparable` and I want to sort it, I create a `Comparator`, something like this:

```
public class MyClassComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
        return (o1.getMyField()).compareTo(o2.getMyField());
    }
}
```

This, of course, sorts MyClass objects according to the natural ordering of MyClass.MyField. But I want the reverse order.

I could of course just hardcode the reverse order in the `compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2)` method. Something like

```
if (o1.getMyField()).compareTo(o2.getMyField()) > 0 return -1;
if (o1.getMyField()).compareTo(o2.getMyField()) < 0 return 1;
return 0;
```

Anoter alternative is leaving the code of MyClassComparator as I initially suggested, and using `public static <T> Comparator<T> reverseOrder(Comparator<T> cmp)` from `java.util.Collections` to pass an instance of `MyClassComparator` and get a reverse comparator.

And a third alternative, that I think is wrong, could be sorting my `LinkedList<MyClass>` with the natural order Comparator and fetch the elements from last to first. `LinkedList` is a doubly linked list, so it should handle this perfectly. The problem is that I would always have to get a specific `Iterator` instead of just using a `for each` loop (minor) and, of course, that I initially wanted to sort ANY sortable structure, and I can't guarantee that it will be a doubly linked list or anything that handles well iterating through it in reverse order.

Considering that I'm quite certain (can't ever be 100% certain) that I won't be using the natural order of `MyClass` objects, just the reverse order, what would be the best way to obtain my reverse comparator?

Thank you.

Comment: You could: Compare `o2` or `o1` instead...`(o2.getMyField()).compareTo(o1.getMyField())`; use `Collections.reverse` or as you stated, use `Collections.reverseOrder`, which I think would be the most efficient, as you're not double processing the collection

Comment: @Blueriver Not sure what you really mean by 'best' way, the solutions you outlined yourself are all sound :)
Personally, I have used the `reverseOrder()` option successfully and I find it the cleanest: you build your comparator to sort you items in ascending order, and just get one that does the exact opposite with one elegant line of code.

Comment: Thanks @NotSoOldNick. Guess by "best" I mean cleanest, easiest to maintain, and of course as efficient as possible.

@MadProgrammer using reverse() is out of the question, since javadoc says "This method runs in linear time." , meaning it iterates over a sorted Collection to sort it in reverse. That's not efficient at all, if I can just sort my Collection in reverse order from the start.
Comparing o2 with o1 instead of o1 with o2 does sound nice. Will it do the job? Creating a `Comparator` with `o2.getMyField().compareTo(o1.getMyField())` instead of the one I proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a comparator would be the correct approach here in order to avoid the overhead of reversing an array. If the classes you are comparing implement Comparable you can just reverse the order of the comparison. `obj2.compareTo(obj1)`. A way to visualize this is to think of the two objects as integers and compareTo as subtracting them.

Comment: No `Comparable` on `MyClass`, but `MyClass.myField` does implement `Comparable`. You think the best way is to write a `Comparator` that does `o2.getMyField().compareTo(o1.getMyField())` instead of the `o1.getMyField().compareTo(o2.getMyField())` I initially created?

Comment: Reversing the order seems like a simpler and faster solution as you do not need to check and change the values.